# Number of ways to schedule tours

Tags: combinatorics

You are a tour guide and want to schedule tours for 4 different tourists. You have eight different time slots available for tours and want to schedule each tourist exactly twice. However, one of the tourists is unable to attend the first time slot you have available. How many different ways are there to schedule tours for the 4 tourists?

I know that if the restriction on the single tourist and the first time slot was removed, the solution would be: $$\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$ However, one of the tourists only has seven different spots to choose 2 from, so is the solution now $$\binom{7}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$

Comment: Looks good. Equivalently, note that exactly one fourth of the unrestricted solutions put our late riser in the first slot, so you could just multiply the unrestricted number by $\frac 34$.